# Angular2 DI: Injecting a global extended service (Can't resolve all parameters)

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I have just upgraded my Ionic app codebase to ng2 Release, using AngularFire2. In the codebase, I have a global service called FirebaseService which extends AngularFire.

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService extends AngularFire {

  constructor(firebaseConfig: string, auth: AngularFireAuth, database: FirebaseDatabase) {
      super(firebaseConfig, auth, database);
  }

...

}
```

In my `app.component.ts` I include FirebaseService in the `providers` array (I have tried both `FirebaseService` and `{ provide: AngularFire, useClass: FirebaseService }`). However, when I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DiscoverPage: (NavController, GlobalService, ?, Events).
```

Constructor for `DiscoverPage` is as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'catalogue-discover',
  templateUrl: 'catalogue-discover.html'
})

export class DiscoverPage {
  constructor(private nav: NavController, 
              private global: GlobalService,
              public firebase: FirebaseService, 
              private events: Events) {
  }

...

}
```

The '?' points to FirebaseService - I get the feeling that I did not perform the DI properly. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Please post the code (class declaration and constructor) of `DiscoverPage`

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems:

1. As mentioned by @shinglesmingles, you should add the decorator `Injectable` to your service class declaration
2. Avoid circular references, though they generally work, there are cases they don't

Example of [2]:

```
// file a.ts
export ClassA {}

// file b.ts
import { ClassA } from './';

export ClassB { 
  // using ClassA somehow
}

// file index.ts
export * from './a';
export * from './b';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Injectable()` decorator to your service.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put that in the code snippet. `@Injectable()` is definitely in there, as it was working before I upgraded to Angular2 Release.

Comment: Oh ok, the solution is not that easy so ;)